# exception HREsult 0x8002000b disp_e_badindex in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, excel, exception

I am exporting dataset to Excel. When trying with 3 Excel sheets, it is working fine. But if I try with a fourth sheet, it shows this exception.

```
exception HREsult 0x8002000b disp_e_badindex
```

Is there any answer for this?

Comment: Show your code and tell us what have you tried.. People can't read your mind.

Comment: was it helpful for you? Please read kb922848

Answer (score 0):

This may be the group policy.

Take a look at [kb  922848](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922848/en-us)